# El código que tengo para el super.onBackPressed(); hace que las imagenes se me devuelve duplicadas, y tengo que llamarlo dos veces para que funcione

Tags: java, android

El problema que tengo es que para el `onBackPressed` quiero que tenga dos funciones:

1. Cerrar el `NavigationView` si ese está abierto.
2. Que los iconos del `BottomNavigationView` se cambien solos según el fragmento en que esté el usuario

Ambas cosas funcionan, pero tengo que llamar dos veces a `super.onBackPressed();`

Ahora, el problema es que al llamarlo dos veces las imágenes en dos de los fragmentos se me devuelve duplicadas, pero si quito uno de los ````super.onBackPressed();``` la página no se cambia. se vuelve a cargar la misma página en que estés, pero no te vuelve a la página anterior.

Cómo puedo escribir yo el código como para llamar al `super.onBackPressed();` solo una vez para que las imágenes no se me devuelva duplicadas?

**Así lo tengo ahora, y las imágenes se me devuelve duplicadas**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
        } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
        } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
        } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**También lo he intentado a hacer así, pero entonces la página no se cambia...**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
            } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
            } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
            } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
            }
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**BottomNavigationView MainActivity**

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = menuItem -> {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                mSelectedFragment = new TabLayoutFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notifications:
                seenNotification();
                mSelectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());
                editor.apply();
                mSelectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_save:
                mSelectedFragment = new AttendingEventFragment();
                break;
        }

        if (mSelectedFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectedFragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

        return true;
    };
```

Comment: A que imagenes te refieres que se cargan dos veces?

Comment: @Jorgesys tengo imagenes en el ```ProfileFragment``` que se cargan dos veces, pero lo he comprobado y sé que es porque llamo dos veces al ```super.onBackPressed();```, pero si no lo hago ni me vuelve a la página anterior, ni el ```NavigationView``` se cierra... Hay mejor forma de escribir ese código en ```onBackPressed();``` para que haga ambas cosas y solo tenga que llamar a ```onBackPressed();``` tan solo una vez?

Answer (score 0):

Si las imágenes y otros elementos aparecen duplicados es porque estas creando instancias del fragmento y asignándolas al contenedor mas de una vez. Debes manejar la pila de fragmentos usando banderas, o simplemente añadiendo un fragmento si aun no esta añadido, y en el caso de regresar al anterior, ocultar el actual y mostrar el anterior, es un juego de añadir-ocultar-mostrar según se requiera. Aquí un ejemplo guardando un historial usando el enfoque inicial que tenias (usando `replace` para cada transacción).

```
package cm.aptoide.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView navView;
    List<String> historic = new ArrayList<>();
    int MAX_HISTORIC = 5; //Cambiar de acuerdo al historial que desees implementar

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                setSelected(item,false);
                return false;
            }
        });
        navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
    }

    private void setSelected(MenuItem item,boolean isBack) {
        Fragment mSelectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mSelectedFragment = new TabLayoutFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mSelectedFragment = new AttendingEventFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mSelectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
        }
        if (mSelectedFragment != null) {
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, mSelectedFragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            if(!isBack)saveHistoric(String.valueOf(item.getTitle()));
            item.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    private void saveHistoric(String currentItem) {

        int i = historic.size();
        if(i != 0) {
            if (i < MAX_HISTORIC) {
                if (!historic.get(i - 1).equals(currentItem)) {
                    historic.add(currentItem);
                }
            } else {
                if (!historic.get(i - 1).equals(currentItem)) {
                    historic.add(currentItem);
                    historic.remove(0);
                }
            }
        }else historic.add(currentItem);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(historic.size() > 1) {
            switch (historic.get(historic.size() - 2)) {
                case "Home":
                    setSelected(navView.getMenu().getItem(0),true);
                    break;
                case "Dashboard":
                    setSelected(navView.getMenu().getItem(1),true);
                    break;
                case "Notifications":
                    setSelected(navView.getMenu().getItem(2),true);
                    break;
            }
            historic.remove(historic.size() - 1);
        }else
            finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: De acuerdo, pero me puedes indicar cómo lo puedo cambiar con el código que tengo allí arriba? Po ejemplo, arriba puedes ver el que pone como lo tengo ahora, y seguro que es eso, pero que harias tu diferent con ese código?

Comment: El código que adjuntas esta bien, deberías editarlo e incluir la parte donde se asignan los fragmentos al seleccionar cada ítem, porque es allí donde se verifica que procedimiento realizar

Comment: Acabo de subirlo. Echale un vistazo por favor. Ademas, en el metodo super.onBackPressed(); lo llamo dos veces que no esta bien, verdad? Hay otra forma de hacerlo, escribirlo para que solo lo llame una vez?

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que `fragment` tiene un valor no nulo?, porque puede ser que nunca se cumpla el condicional

Comment: Por qué iba a tener un valor nulo?? Acabo de comprobarlo y me parece que sí, pero cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: edite mi respuesta con un proyecto rápido, esta funcionando. Espero puedas adecuarlo al tuyo.

Comment: @MarcosF. gracias por tu respuesta pero recuerda seguir la guía [answer], puedes agregar pseudocódigo o agregar el código relacionado a el que agrega johnnn en su pregunta, saludos.

Comment: @MarcosF. tío, no me está funcionando... No sé cómo lo hago para que funcione. Me echas una mano?

Comment: claro, solo cuéntame: ¿sigues teniendo el mismo error?, ¿que modificaciones realizaste?, por favor sé mas especifico.

Comment: Bueno, he hecho lo que me has puesto allí arriba, pero lo único que pasa es que la app se cierra, no crashea, pero me saca de la app. Me imagino que es por el finish() al final de todo. Podemos hablar en el chat?

Comment: @johnnn seguro que si

Comment: Algún consejo? Es que no sé cómo hacere que se cambien los iconos solos sin devolverme las imágenes duplicadas... A lo mejor sabes alguna otra forma de escribir el código en onBackPressed();..?

Comment: Tu implementacion con una sola llamada de debería funcionar, la razón por la que no cambian los fragmentos es porque has planteado de forma incorrecta la lógica: cuando buscas el fragmento con `findFragmentById()` te devolverá el fragmento que se esta mostrando actualmente y luego en los siguientes ìf` buscas el mismo fragmento para mostrarlo de nuevo. Puedes implementar un historial de navegación como lo hice en mi ejemplo, o definir una prioridad de navegación, ya te mostré como hacer lo primero, pero para el segundo caso seria mas fácil, a continuación te muestro como hacerlo...

Comment: en tu caso `ProfileFragment` tendria la prioridad mas baja, por lo que dentro del ultimo `else if` deberias seleccionar al siguiente fragmento en prioridad: `mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);`, en el segundo `else if` iria `mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);`, en el primero `mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);`. Y por ultimo dado que el primer fragmento es el de mayor prioridad puedes cerrar la aplicación o si existe, regresar a una actividad. Finalmente recuerda no llamar `super.onBackPressed` para que funcione.